# Prove that max weighted independent set is NP hard using k-Independent Set

Tags: complexity-theory

Max weighted independent set returns a set of nodes that form the maximum weighted independent set. K-independent set returns yes/no if the graph has a independent set of size k. How would you go about proving this?

Comment: Maximum weighted independent set is an optimization problem. NP-hardness is a category of decision problems. So the first step would be formulating the decision problem corresponding to your optimization problem. Once you do that, the reduction should become obvious.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It's entirely standard to describe a function problem as **NP**-hard  if an oracle for it would let you decide **NP**-complete problems in polytime.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thank you! I understand now